# Simplest way to display image coming from database using Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, sqlite

What is the simplest and easiest way to display images that came from database using Ruby on Rails?
And what I mean about easiest and simplest is the fewest steps in doing the thing.

What I want to do is to get/retrieve the images/blob datatype that I have stored in the database and then show in my website.

Comment: Are you storing the image into database and want to show that in browser?
Or the image is being stored ito some buckets and want retrieve the url of image from database and show that?

Comment: You can use https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data. Look at "Display an image Active Record in the browser:" bit.

Answer (score 0):

The "simplest way" in terms of lines of code is to just create an image tag with a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
module ImagesHelper
  def data_url_image(binary, mime_type: 'image/jpg', **kwargs)
    tag.img src: "data:#{mime_type};base64,#{Base64.encode64(binary)}",
            **kwargs
  end
end
```

However it will also bloat the document and may be slower then linking to an actual URI by an order of magnitude. There is also no shortage of libraries for this (like ActiveStorage) so there are probally more fun things to do then spend your time reinventing the wheel.